# Accessing selected node of richfaces tree from Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, tree, richfaces

This should be a very simple question. I have a richfaces tree that is rendered using JSF. When the user clicks on a node I want a javascript function to run. Nothing more nothing less. No redirects, no re-submit, no-rerender, no Ajax. Just plain old Javascript.

I have seen the **onselected** attribute of the tree and it indeed fires a Javascript method. But of course I want to know which node was clicked.

Here is what I have so far

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function documentClicked(nodeRef)
{
    alert("Node is "+nodeRef);
}

</script>
</head>


    <rich:tree switchType="client" value="#{ajaxDocumentTree.rootNode}"  
        var="document" onselected="documentClicked()" >



        <rich:treeNode   iconLeaf="../images/tree/doc.gif"
            icon="../images/tree/doc.gif">

            <h:outputText value="#{document.friendlyName}" />

        </rich:treeNode>
```

But this does not work because nodeRef is undefined. I expected that the first argument of the callback would be the selected node but this is not the case.

So the question is this:

How do I fire a Javascript function with the selected node from a richfaces tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that the javascript code should be on the node level instead of the tree level.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function documentClicked(nodeRef)
{
    alert("Node id is "+nodeRef);
}

</script>
</head>


    <rich:tree switchType="client" value="#{ajaxDocumentTree.rootNode}"  
        var="document" >

        <rich:treeNode onclick="documentClicked('#{document.id}')">

            <h:outputText value="#{document.friendlyName}" />

        </rich:treeNode>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I have little experience with JSF, but shouldn't *this* (in the scope of your event handler) be referring to the selected node, as it usually does in JavaScript?</strike>

Change your function to this and try it out:

```
function documentClicked()
{
    alert("Node is " + this);
}
```

EDIT: the above was obviously not correct. As per my comment below, change your JSF to

```
<rich:tree switchType="client" value="#{ajaxDocumentTree.rootNode}"  
        var="document" onselected="documentClicked(this)" >
```

Comment: I thought the same thing! I have already tried it. "This" refers to the whole browser window and not the selected node.

Comment: Do you have a public URL to your test page? I am really suspicious towards these Java/JSF-to-JavaScript frameworks. Probably because I don't know them well, but it would help very much to see what kind of JS-code was generated in the end. Then we can see how documentClicked actually is called, in reality.

Comment: OK, I am being stupid, it's obvious from your code how documentClicked is called. Keep your original function and call it in onselected like this: documentClicked(this).